# Font changes when VF page is rendered as pdf

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, attachment, custom-link

I am creating a letter by getting the custom fields of a custom object(plan review__c). I was able to add a save button link to the bottom and save the letter as pdf in Notes and attachement section. below is my VF page for that:

```
<apex:page standardController="Plan_Reviews__c" showHeader="false" extensions="BuildingProCertObjectionSheet">
<apex:form >
<apex:image url="{!imageURL}" style="width:720px" ></apex:image>
<br></br><br></br>
<!-- Added new text as a part of support request -->
<apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="720px">
<h1 style="font-size:20px;"> PRO-CERT CHECKLIST</h1>
</apex:panelGrid>
<!-- end -->

 <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="720px">

   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="60%">

         <!--  <p style="font-size:18px;">FPIMS:</p> <apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.FPIMS__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/>-->

           <p style="font-size:18px;">Premise: <apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Establishment_Address__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>

   </apex:panelGrid>
   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="40%">         
           <p style="font-size:18px;">Date:<apex:outputText value="{!currentdate}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>
   </apex:panelGrid>
   <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="60%">
           <span style="font-size:18px;">DOB Job Number:<apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.DOB_Job_Number__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/></span>   
           <!--<p style="font-size:18px;">Name of Contractor:<apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Contractor_Name__r.Name}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>-->
   </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:panelGrid>  

<div id="container1" style="width:720px">

  <p style="font-size:18px;">Pro-Cert plans submitted to NYC Business Acceleration have been examined and found to be unacceptable at this time. This plan will be re-examined after the following defects are corrected:</p>
</div>

<div id="container2" style="width:720px">
 <apex:repeat value="{!objlist}" var="d">
    <tr>
    <td><apex:outputText value="{!d}" style="font-size:18px;" /></td><br></br>
    </tr>
 </apex:repeat>
</div>

<div id="container3" style="width:720px">
   <p style="font-size:18px;"><b>Additional Objection(s):</b><apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Other_Violations__c}" style="font-size:18px;"/></p>
   <!-- <p style="font-size:18px;">By Order of Chief of Fire Prevention<br></br> 
    By&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Assigned_Reviewer_Title__c}"/>&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!Plan_Reviews__c.Assigned_Reviewer_s_Email__c}"/></p> -->
</div>

<apex:commandButton action="{!Savecopy}" disabled="false" value="Save"/>

</apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

When I hit save here I get an pdf in notes and attachment section of my page. The problem - the font in the pdf is very different from what I use in above VF force page. How does the font in pdf changes automatically , it differs from the font in VF page(above) from which is converted to that pdf. Any idea?

Here is the apex class which is related to this page:

```
public class BuildingProCertObjectionSheet {
   private final ApexPages.StandardController controller;
   private final Id                           planreviewID;
   public String imageURL{get;set;}
   public List<String> objlist {get;set;} 
   public string currentdate {get; set;}
   public BuildingProCertObjectionSheet(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        controller   = stdController;
        planreviewID = (Id)controller.getRecord().get('Id');
        Date dt = Date.today();
        currentdate = dt.format();
        list<Plan_Reviews__c> prlist = [select Pro_Cert_Objections_for_Letter__c from Plan_Reviews__c where id = :planreviewID limit 1];
        string obj;
        for(Plan_Reviews__c pr: prlist){
           obj = pr.Pro_Cert_Objections_for_Letter__c;    
        }
        if(obj!=null){
           list<string> objections = obj.split(';'); 
           integer i =1;
           objlist = new list<string>();
           for(string o : objections){
              objlist.add(i++ +'. '+o);
           }
        }
        imageURL='/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=';
        List< document > documentList=[select name from document where Name='RangehoodObjectionLogo'];
        if(documentList.size()>0)
        {
           imageURL=imageURL+documentList[0].id;
        }   
   }     

   public PageReference Savecopy(){
      PageReference p = Page.RangehoodObjectionSheet;
      blob b = ApexPages.currentPage().getContentAsPDF ();

      Attachment a = new Attachment();
      a.body = b;
      a.name = 'Building Pro-Cert Objection Sheet '+currentdate+'.pdf';
      a.parentid = planreviewID;

      insert a;

      PageReference pref = new PageReference('/'+planreviewID);
      return pref;
   }
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the PDF when you call the saveCopy method on your controller?

Comment: Please see the edit, I have similar content in one more VF page which I also convert to pdf , but I do not see any font changes in that pdf. I the VF page code is almost same for both page, specially the styling part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a Salesforce documentation [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm) for the supported fonts in PDF created by VisualForce. Make sure you are selecting one of them.

[image]